# How to query the custom fields by language in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, lang

For each post, there is a custom field name "Function", the key/value pair is like this:

```
Key : Functions
Value : <!--en-->Nourishing Yin and invigorating the vital essence of kidneys.<!--:--><!--tw-->滋陰補腎。<!--:-->
```

The problem is if I simply use get_post_meta , it return string of both language, how can I get the value based on the language?

I am using qTranslate right now, Thanks.

Updated (the code):

```
$custom_fields = get_post_custom(get_the_ID());
$function = get_post_custom_values('Functions', get_the_ID());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply fetch the strings considering comments as prefix and suffix -

After you get the custom field value,

e.g.

```
$function = "<!--en-->Nourishing Yin and invigorating the vital essence of kidneys.<!--:--><!--tw-->滋陰補腎。<!--:-->";

$arr = explode("<!--:-->", $function);

$new_arr = array();

foreach($arr as $a ){

 if(!empty($a)){
    $lang = str_replace( "-->", "", substr($a, 4, 5) );
    $str = substr($a, 9);
    $new_arr[$lang] = $str;
 }

}
```

Now $new_arr will have key/value pairs like array(language_code => sentence).

If you do print_r($new_arr);

It will give output as follows:

```
Array ( [en] => Nourishing Yin and invigorating the vital essence of kidneys. [tw] => 滋陰補腎。 )
```

Now you can identify the strings using their respective language codes.